# $\int_\Omega f d\mu = 0 $ if and only if $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

can someone give me a hint on what kind of theorem/definition I should make use of to solve this?

Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak A, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ a non-negative measurable function.
 Show that
$$\int_\Omega f d\mu = 0 $$ if and only if $$f(x)=0$$ a.e.

Comment: This is a simple application of Chebyshev's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One side:

Let it be that the nonnegative $f$ is not $0$ a.e.

That means exactly that a measurable set $A$ exists with $\mu A>0$ and $f(a)>0$ for $a\in A$.

Defining $A_n:=\{a\in A\mid f(a)\geq\frac1{n}\}$ we have $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ and consequently $\mu A_n>0$ for $n$ large enough (since $\mu A_n\to\mu A$ in this situation).

Then $f\geq\frac1n1_{A_n}$ leads to $\int fd\mu\geq\int\frac1{n}1_{A_n}d\mu=\frac1{n}\mu A_n>0$.

Other side:

If $f=0$ a.e. then for every stepfunction (i.e. measurable function taking only finite nonnegative values) $g=\sum_{i=1}^n c_n1_{B_n}\leq f$ we will have have $\mu B_i=0$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and consequently $\int gd\mu=0$.

By definition $\int fd\mu$ is the supremum of such values $\int gd\mu$ so evidently $\int fd\mu=0$

Comment: Stupid question of me. But what does the $1_{A_N}$ mean?

Comment: The characteristic function of set $A_n$. it takes value $1$ is $x\in A_n$ and $0$ otherwise. It agrees with $\chi_{A_n}$ as used in the answer of Mathematician 42.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch:

(1) Suppose not, then there is a positive measure subset $A$ where $f\not=0$.

(2) Let $A_n$ be the set of points where $f>\frac{1}{n}$.

(3) Observe that $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$ and $\bigcup A_n=A$.

(4) Conclude that some $A_n$ has positive measure using the properties of measures.

(5) Conclude that $\int f d\mu\geq\frac{1}{n}\mu(A_n)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose there is some measurable set $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$ such that $f>0$ on $E$. Notice that $f\geq f\chi_E$ where $\chi_E$ is the indicator function of $E$. It follows that $$\int_{\Omega}f\mathrm{d}\mu\geq \int_{\Omega}f\chi_E\mathrm{d}\mu>0.$$

Explain this last inequality in detail. Can you do the other implication yourself?

Comment: As written, the first line is some what confusing.  To me, $f\not=0$ almost everywhere means that the set where $f$ is zero is measure zero.  I think that you mean that it is not the case that $f=0$ almost everywhere.  The difficulty deals with the following parsing: $f$ is (not equal to zero almost everywhere) vs $f$ is not (equal to zero almost everywhere).

Comment: Absolutely right, stupid mistake.

Comment: Can I ask why $f\geq f\chi_E$? We haven't got too deep into the indicator functions yet, I really want to understand every single step I'm doing.

Comment: So $$\chi_E(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{ if $x\in E$}\\
0 & \mbox{ else}.
\end{cases}$$ Hence $$(f\chi_{E})(x)=f(x)\chi_{E}(x)=\begin{cases}f(x) & \mbox{ if $x\in E$}\\
0  & \mbox{else}.\end{cases}\leq f(x)$$ for all $x\in \Omega$.

Answer (score -1):

If @$f(x) = 0$ a.e. is clear that $\int_{\Omega} fd\mu = 0$.

Now, suppose that $f$ is non-negative, $\int_{\Omega} fd\mu = 0$, but $f$ is not $0$ a.e. It means that there is $A$ such that $\mu(A) >0$ and $f(x) \neq 0, \forall x \in A$.

Then,

$\int_{\Omega} f d\mu \geq \int_{A} f d\mu > 0$. Contradiction!

Comment: The content of this question, to me, is why $\int_Afd\mu$ is positive ...

Comment: Ok.. You are integrating a positive function on a set of positive measure! It is positive, right?

Comment: Sure, it's positive, but I think that the point of this problem is to prove that statement using the properties of measurable sets.

Comment: If I recall my measure theory correctly this proof is incorrect. The monotonicity of the integral only holds as a non-strict inequality. If $f > 0$ in some set, we cannot immediately conclude that the integral of $f$ is greater than 0, that is in fact what we are trying to prove here in a sense.

Comment: That was my intuitive idea, but it seems like in measure theory intuition is not good.. So I should go for the proof using the properties of measurable sets as @Michael Burr suggested right

Comment: You must at least explain why $\mu A>0$ combined with $f(x)>0$ on $A$ leads to $\int_A fd\mu>0$