# $\int_{\Omega}f(x)d\nu(x)=0$ implies $f=0$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\nu)$ be a measurable space with $\nu$ a positive $\sigma$-additive measure on $\Sigma$ and le $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that,
$$
\int_{\Omega}f(x)d\nu(x)=0
$$
Does this imply that $f=0\quad \nu-\ a.e.$ ?

Any hint will be appreciated :) thank you for your time !

Comment: The theorem is true iff $f\ge 0$ $\nu$-almost everywhere. PS: you usually use *almost surely* only if the measure is a probability measure.

Comment: yes you're right,  actually I was working on probability measures :) I will edit it right away.

Comment: @hounda anyways, my comment reflects this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784957/int-omega-f-d-mu-0-if-and-only-if-fx-0-almost-everywhere?rq=1

Comment: can give me a hint of the proof please :) @b00nheT

Comment: Yes: Simply assume not and complete the contradiction. The accepted answer in the above question gives the exact solution. Just read the first lines if you want some hints on how to start the contrapositive argument

Comment: yes I've seen it, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

How about $ f(x)= x $ on $\Omega = (-1,1)$ and $\nu $ the lebesgue measure?

Comment: yes you're right !!! I didn't see this, but still I've seen this result somewhere :/ maybe they are some conditions so that it can be true ! what do you think ?

Comment: Thanks @Ant, @ b00n heT above gave this condition.

Answer (score 1):

This result is true if and only if $f\geq0$ almost everywhere. Ant gave an example of where this result is fault when this condition is not true.

As for the proof when $f\geq0$, here goes:

$v(\{x\in\Omega|f(x)>0\})=\sum_2^\infty v(\{x\in\Omega|\frac{1}{n}\leq f(x)\leq\frac{1}{n-1}\})+v(\{x\in\Omega|f(x)>1\})$.

Now, assume any of the summands had measure bigger than $0$, then it is obvious that the integral would have positive measure. (Since if some set $X$ had measure $\alpha$ and $f\geq \gamma$ over $X$ then $\int_X f\geq \gamma\alpha$)

Thus, $f$ is $0$ almost everywhere.